# three.js : Pass text instead of particles into particle cloud

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, word-cloud

I have a forked three.js codepen experiment that has square particles floating around.

But i'm trying to modify it such that i can pass text (geometry?) into it, replacing the square particles, somewhat like a word / tag cloud. Is this possible?

Link to current codepen:
https://codepen.io/farisk/pen/pWQGxB

Heres what i wish to achieve:
[image]

I'm currently not sure where to start.

I was thinking of somehow using a text geometry

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
let font = loader.parse(fontJSON);
var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry("hello", {font: font, size: 120, height: 10, material: 0});
```

But someone mentioned that this is not the right way? I'm pretty new to three.js / html canvas so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Passing in geometry per particle is usually not possible in particle systems because the fact that its the same geometry for each particle is what makes these systems efficient.

To achieve the effect that you are looking for there are basically two options:

- Render all texts into a single sprite texture and provide texture coordinates for each particle such that each particle renders the correct text. (Only two dimensional rendering of the text and not scalable for a large amount of texts) See this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=sprite#webgl_points_sprites).
- Make each text object it's own geometry and render them without a particle system. (You loose the performance gain of particle systems)

If you really just want to achieve a tag cloud you could also just use pure JavaScript and transform the position of the text elements according to some calculated 3D positions.

Comment: Alright i'll probably settle for something like TagCanvas.js then. Thanks for the tip.